# How to extract these integer values from ArrayList<String>

Tags: java, android, arraylist, number-formatting

I am having a `ArrayList<String> abc` in which I am getting this value      `[64.3, 25.1, 44.3, 34.2, 6.4, 48.5, 35.5, 59.5, 54.6, 26.6, 11.2, 50.3, 25.1]`

Now I want to extract the integer values from it such as `64,25,44,34,6,48,35,59,54,26,11,50,25` and put these values in an integer array `int[] cab`

How can I get this? How to remove the decimal and after decimal values from it?

Comment: but this is ArrayList<string> not double array

Comment: @AndroidGeek Don't you think that would be a very important piece of information to add to the question? *(click "edit" link)* I mean, it looks like an `ArrayList<Double>` to anyone else, so saying that they are `String` objects is kinda important, you know.

Comment: use the iterator to extract the value from array list and cast to int

Comment: @Andreas I have mentioned it in the question topic

Comment: why people have downvoted my question without reading it carefully. It''s not my mistake it's the readers mistake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are three different (but similar) ways of doing it, depending on Java version and/or preferences:

```
ArrayList<String> abc = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(
        "64.3", "25.1", "44.3", "34.2", "6.4", "48.5", "35.5",
        "59.5", "54.6", "26.6", "11.2", "50.3", "25.1" ));
System.out.println("abc = " + abc);

// Loop (all Java versions)
int[] cab1 = new int[abc.size()];
for (int i = 0; i < cab1.length; i++)
    cab1[i] = (int)Double.parseDouble(abc.get(i));
System.out.println("cab1 = " + Arrays.toString(cab1));

// Java 8 stream with lambda expression
int[] cab2 = abc.stream()
                .mapToInt(v -> (int)Double.parseDouble(v))
                .toArray();
System.out.println("cab2 = " + Arrays.toString(cab2));

// Java 8 stream with method references
int[] cab3 = abc.stream()
                .map(Double::valueOf)
                .mapToInt(Double::intValue)
                .toArray();
System.out.println("cab3 = " + Arrays.toString(cab3));
```

**Output**

```
abc = [64.3, 25.1, 44.3, 34.2, 6.4, 48.5, 35.5, 59.5, 54.6, 26.6, 11.2, 50.3, 25.1]
cab1 = [64, 25, 44, 34, 6, 48, 35, 59, 54, 26, 11, 50, 25]
cab2 = [64, 25, 44, 34, 6, 48, 35, 59, 54, 26, 11, 50, 25]
cab3 = [64, 25, 44, 34, 6, 48, 35, 59, 54, 26, 11, 50, 25]
```

Comment: Loop (all Java versions) it is giving me index out of bound exception

Comment: @AndroidGeek I executed that code to generate that output, so you must have copied it incorrectly.

Comment: Ok I am doing it again

Comment: tried it again but still same error java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=13; index=13 :(

Answer (score 1):

Simply iterate:

```
int[] cab = new int[abc.size()];
for(int i = 0; i < cab.length; i++){
    cab[i] = (int)Float.parseFloat(abc.get(i));
}
```

Comment: cannot cast java.lang.string to int

Comment: What is the type of your List `abc` ?

Comment: I have mentioned it is string

Comment: not in the first version. Anyway, check the edited answer.

Comment: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "64.3"

Comment: @AndroidGeek check my answer

Comment: My answer does not parse int but floats

Answer (score 1):

Try This :

```
Integer cab[] = new Integer[abc.size()];
cab= abc.toArray(cab);

//iterating array
for (Integer cabs: cab) {
System.out.println("cab= " + cabs);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. string to double
2. double to int

   ```
   for(int i = 0 ; i < abc.size(); ++i) {
       tmp = Double.parseDouble(abc.get(i));
       cab[i] = (int)tmp;
       System.out.println(cab[i]);
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

In Java 8:

```
int[] cab = abc.stream()
        .map(Double::valueOf)
        .mapToInt(Double::intValue)
        .toArray();
```

Comment: it cannot resolve symbol stream()

Comment: @AndroidGeek Well, if you're using Android, you don't have Java 8.

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<Integer> newList = new ArrayList<Integer>(stringsList.size());
for (String myInt : strings){
    int intVal = (int)Double.parseDouble(myInt);
    newList.add(intVal);
}
```

where stringsList is your Arraylist

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
Iterator itr = al.iterator();
          while(itr.hasNext()) {

             String s1=itr.next().toString();
             Double d=new Double(s1);
             int s2=d.intValue();
             System.out.print(s2 + " ");
          }
```

Comment: Why not use a `for` loop? Why not use generics? `Double.parseDouble(s1)` would be better, since it doesn't create a wrapper object for the result.